# ¿Como incremento el valor de una columna con laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un portal donde un usuario puede publicar ofertas y cada vez que el usuario agregue una oferta, quiero que se le sume un punto y se guarde en la base de datos.

El controlador lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
    public function crear(Request $request){
    $ofertaNueva = new App\Oferta;
    $puntos = App\User::find(auth()->id());

    $ofertaNueva->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $ofertaNueva->imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public');
    $ofertaNueva->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $ofertaNueva->fecha = Carbon::now();
    $ofertaNueva->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;
    $ofertaNueva->user_id = auth()->id();

    $puntos->points = +1;

    $ofertaNueva->save();
    $puntos->save();
    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Oferta agregada');
}
```

Como se puede ver, en **$puntos->points** tengo un "+1", pero no se suma al valor que tenia antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aumentar el valor de una columna determinada, puedes usar el método [increment()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#increment-and-decrement), el cual acepta al menos un argumento: la columna a modificar.

Opcionalmente, se puede pasar un segundo argumento para controlar la cantidad por la cual la columna debe incrementarse.

Para tu caso puedes obtener el usuario autenticado que hace el request con `App\User::find(auth()->id())`, y aplicarle increment a la columna `points`. Opcionalmente, la cantidad a incrementar, pero no es necesario si solo quieres que se incremente en 1:

```
App\User::find(auth()->id())->increment('points');
```

O sea, que tu función quedaría así:

```
public function crear(Request $request){
    $ofertaNueva = new App\Oferta;
    $ofertaNueva->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $ofertaNueva->imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public');
    $ofertaNueva->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $ofertaNueva->fecha = Carbon::now();
    $ofertaNueva->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;
    $ofertaNueva->user_id = auth()->id();
    $ofertaNueva->save();

    App\User::find(auth()->id())->increment('points');

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Oferta agregada');
}
```

Solo como ejemplo si quisieras incrementar la columna en 5:

```
App\User::find(auth()->id())->increment('points', 5);
```